# Using vaadin in complex project

Tags: maven, model-view-controller, vaadin

I'm working on a new project for a company as part of a university course.
The project is security report generator,
reports that might come up as a Word file actually tell me where there are security problems for the company that I checked and I fill out the report by the findings.
I consulted with university professor and he recommended me to Vaadin.
i want from the best and here we have the best,
so I would like to know what do you guys think and what do you recommend I use?
What kind of projects fits to work VAADIN?
Can I build a project part of it is VAADIN and part of it is an MVC architecture together?

tnx for the answers.

Comment: plz anyone who knows vaadin and can help me to understand

Comment: Yes, you can build this type of project with Vaadin. Your post is too vague, though, and doesn't contain any answerable questions. Please, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: This is much too open-ended for a Question on Stack Overflow. Start with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin), then go through the [Vaadin.com](https://vaadin.com/home) site with extensive explanations, documentation, video demos they publish on YouTube, and online demo apps showing the widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Vaadin together with spring-boot: http://vaadin.github.io/spring-tutorial/

How to setup the MVC architecture could be found here: https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-architecture.html
But you should also use spring-IoC (dependency injection) as well to connect the code modules easily.